# How to initialize a Thread in Kotlin?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin

In Java it works by accepting an object which implements runnable :

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new myRunnable())
```

where `myRunnable` is a class implementing `Runnable`.

But when I tried this in Kotlin, it doesn't seems to work:

```
var myThread:Thread = myRunnable:Runnable
```

Comment: `var myThread = Thread(myRunnable())`

Comment: @Mibac It Worked!! Can you help me understand this piece of code?

Comment: Doing `myThread:Thread` says that variable `myThread` is of type `Thread`. And doing `myRunnable:Runnable` has no sense what so ever. Initializing classes in Kotlin is very similar to Java. You just remove the `new` keyword. Relevant Kotlin documentation: [a](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#creating-instances-of-classes), [b](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-local-variables)

Comment: Thanks. So x:X format works for classes but not for interfaces?

Comment: It does work for interfaces but when you do `x = Y:y` the `Y:y` part makes no sense.

Comment: You should take a look at this [guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html) for basic syntax on defining variable and instance.

Comment: Nowadays in Java 5+ we let an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) manage the threads.

Answer (score 87):

Kotlin comes with a standard library function `thread`, which I'd recommend to use here:

```
public fun thread(
    start: Boolean = true, 
    isDaemon: Boolean = false, 
    contextClassLoader: ClassLoader? = null, 
    name: String? = null, 
    priority: Int = -1, 
    block: () -> Unit): Thread
```

You can use it like this:

```
thread {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("test")
}
```

It has many optional parameters for e.g. not starting the thread directly by setting `start` to `false`.

---

**Alternatives**

To initialize an instance of class `Thread`, invoke its constructor:

```
val t = Thread()
```

You may also pass an optional `Runnable` as a lambda (SAM Conversion) as follows:

```
Thread {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("test")
}
```

The more explicit version would be passing an anonymous implementation of `Runnable` like this:

```
Thread(Runnable {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("test")
})
```

Note that the previously shown examples do only *create* an instance of a `Thread` but don't actually start it. In order to achieve that, you need to invoke `start()` explicitly.

Comment: Note that you can omit `start = true` (because `start` is `true` by default) and simply write `thread { Thread.sleep(1000) }` to get started thread.

Comment: I've added a note about this to make it more obvious, thank you

Answer (score 26):

Runnable:

```
val myRunnable = runnable {

}
```

Thread:

```
Thread({  
// call runnable here
  println("running from lambda: ${Thread.currentThread()}")
}).start()
```

You don't see a Runnable here: in Kotlin it can easily be replaced with a lambda expression. Is there a better way? Sure! Here's how you can instantiate and start a 
thread Kotlin-style:

```
thread(start = true) {  
      println("running from thread(): ${Thread.currentThread()}")
    }
```

Comment: @Mibac I provided more choices

Answer (score 13):

I did the following and it appears to be working as expected.

```kotlin
Thread(Runnable {
            //some method here
        }).start()
```

Answer (score 7):

Best way would be to use `thread()` generator function from `kotlin.concurrent`:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html

You should check its default values, as they're quite useful:

```
thread() { /* do something */ }
```

Note that you don't need to call `start()` like in the Thread example, or provide `start=true`.

Be careful with threads that run for a long period of time. It's useful to specify `thread(isDaemon= true)` so your application would be able to terminate correctly.

Usually application will wait until all non-daemon threads terminate.

Comment: Nice and easy solution...what does isDaemon does? Pls explain that in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, create a function for set default properties

```
fun thread(
  start: Boolean = true, 
  isDaemon: Boolean = false, 
  contextClassLoader: ClassLoader? = null, 
  name: String? = null, 
  priority: Int = -1, 
  block: () -> Unit
): Thread
```

then perform background operation calling this function

```
thread(start = true) {
     //Do background tasks...
}
```

Or kotlin coroutines also can be used to perform background task

```
GlobalScope.launch {
 
    //TODO("do background task...")
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // TODO("Update UI")
    }
    //TODO("do background task...")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basic example of `Thread` with `Lamda`

```
fun main() {
    val mylamda = Thread({
        for (x in 0..10){
            Thread.sleep(200)
            println("$x")
        }
   })
    startThread(mylamda)

}

fun startThread(mylamda: Thread) {
    mylamda.start()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
thread { /* your code here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
Thread().run { Thread.sleep(3000); }
```

Comment: Also try to add some explanation

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.

Comment: This code doesn't solve the problem: it doesn't _start_ new thread but executes `Thread.sleep(3000)` in current thread instead (using Kotlin's general [`run` extension method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) which gets newly created thread as a receiver but does nothing with it).

Comment: To simplify @IlyaSerbis's explanation: this answer does not work.  The code within the brackets executes in whatever parent thread is currently running, *not* a new thread.  :(

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    Thread({
        println("test1")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }).start()

    val thread = object: Thread(){
        override fun run(){
            println("test2")
            Thread.sleep(2000)
        }
    }

    thread.start()

    Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 0):

**it's very simple on Kotlin:**

```
Thread {
     // your code here
}.start()
```

**another example:**

```
val thr = Thread {
    // your code here
}
thr.start()
thr.join()
```