# How does Thread() work in Kotlin?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I wanted to execute a task inside a thread and wrote the following code:

```
Thread().run {
    Log.i("TEST", "in thread")
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    transactionStatus = ApiFactory.getInstance().transactionService.abortTransaction()
    synchronized(TestTransactionPayAbort.lock) {
        TestTransactionPayAbort.lock.notify()
    }
}

Log.i("TEST", "main")
synchronized(TestTransactionPayAbort.lock) {
    TestTransactionPayAbort.lock.wait()
}
```

According to the debugger, before executing `Thread().run{}`, I'm inside thread 4.
After executing `Thread.sleep()`, the debugger tells me that thread 4 is sleeping whereas I was expecting to see that thread 5 is sleeping. About the `Log()`: I see immediately *in thread* and *main* 5 seconds later.

What is my mistake here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize a Thread in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505528/how-to-initialize-a-thread-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the syntax you’re looking for is:

```
Thread {
    // your execution code 
}.start()
```

Also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46505671/8073652) for further information.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, it’s mentioned in the linked answer too

Comment: @s1m0nw1, yes you are right about what I'm looking for but what about this [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47700088/3891969) ?